# GLSurfaceView cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm trying to get started with opengl on android.

All tutorials I've found, do assume that GLSurfaceView is available. Whet I'm trying to compile my project, I'm getting

```
GLSurfaceView cannot be resolved to a type
```

I'm assuming that this is because of a missing jar, but I can't find, which jar exactly has to be included.

Can somebody point me to it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add the following import statement to the top of your java file:

```
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
```

Comment: I've tried that, and eclipse simply removes the statement. I'm assuming that's because it can't find the package

Comment: It works fine in my Eclipse install. Are you sure the project is an Android project? Your project must be for API level 3 and above.

Comment: Its android project (3.2), and it works on android simulation just fine, as long as I don't try and use opengl

Comment: ok. I've figured it out at the end; thanks for the suggistion

Answer (score 3):

a much simple way to fix this issue is using the complete package name as following:

```
class YourOwnClass implements android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.Renderer  {
    ...
}
```